# Frappe - Patches do not get executed when installing app and doing bench migrate

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I have created a custom app.

I make patches folder to write patch that update field values in database. I have ensure that it works perfectly.

But when I install the custom app in site, it will add patch entry in tabPatchLog table, but it seems like it doesn't execute patch. And now table has already patch entry, so patch will not run again in bench migrate.

If i delete the patch entry from database and run bench migrate, then it will execute and update field values but it is not a right way.

What should I do, so my patch will execute ?

I tried to see that i have write patch correctly or not.